# Writing sql fetched query data to JSON in python

Tags: python, sql, json

Tring to write sql query fetched data to JSON.

So far the code is:

```
import pymysql.cursors
conn = pymysql.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',user='p****',password='Pr******',db='testdb',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql =  "Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_phone_emp_email,emp_dob from employee where id<5"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
   jsonData = json.dumps(data)
```

The structure I want is

```
 {
     "Employee ID":"1",

    "extra_info": {
     "Employee_name": "Jon Snow",
     "Employee Phone": "9876543210",
     "Employee date of birth": "2017-06-06",
     "Email": "example@email.com"
    }
    }
```

SO it should make 5 files differnt for every emploee.

Note: I am using python3

Comment: That's fine, we're all happy for you. So what have you tried to get the desired output, and what's your question ?

Comment: My question is how do I write the data and save that data locally for every single employee individually.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I am dumping it right now. I don't to how to set and organize data as per sample.

Comment: Going through your comment I feel it can be done..But I don't any approach.Can you help me with the sample code? Making nested dictionary.

Comment: Sorry but I wont. You have all the necessary infos in the answer, and I'm not getting paid to do your job.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you want is named a `dict` (actually 2 nested dicts but...), and is one of the most commonly used data type in Python. Read the doc to learn how to build one. This translates to a "json object" when dumped with `json.dump()`.

wrt/ "individual samples" part, instead of fetching the whole results at once, iterate (`for` loop) over your cursor to get individual rows. Then build the appropriate dict from your row values and `json.dumps()` it to wherever you want.